# Binding ObjectDataProvider to a property instead of a method

Tags: wpf, binding, objectdataprovider

Suppose you have following class:

```
class ProcessController
{
    public List<Process> Active { get { ... } }
    ...
    public List<Process> GetProcesses() { ... }
}
```

I can use the `GetMethod` to bind a `ObjectDataProvider` to the `GetProcesses()` method:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="pList"
                    MethodName="GetProcesses"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type local:ProcessController}"/>
```

My question is, can I also bind to the property `Active`?

If found out that I can do the following:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="pList"
                    MethodName="get_Active"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type local:ProcessController}"/>
```

But somehow this doesn't feel right.

Is there some cleaner way or "right" way to access a property instead of invoking a method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to bind to a property, just bind to the object and use the Path to access the property

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="pList"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type local:ProcessController}"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

The answer given by gcores will not work if the property is static, only if it is an instance member.